# Ubuntu 22.04, Mouse flickering, Keyboard not working (Touchscreen)

Tags: keyboard, xorg, wayland, touchscreen

Today (2022-12-21) I updated my system. I am using 22.04 (as I did before).

But now the keys of the internal (thinkpad p15 laptop) and the external keyboard are not working anymore. The mouse is usable (internal and external).

It works if I switch to a Wayland session before logging in.

This is repeatable: works in Wayland, does not work in X.org.

Up to now I used X.org since screensharing did not work in the past with Wayland.

Are other people experiencing the same issue?

Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason. Today it happend on Wayland, too.

I have a Thinkpad p15 with touch-screen.

I have not cleaned the screen since some time, and the dirt drove the input-handling crazy. The screen created random touch events.

The mouse cursor disappeared again and again, and the keyboard was not usable.

But why did it happen yesterday, and not the days before?

Yesterday and today we have very wet weather (high moisture).

After cleaning the screen the mouse flickering and the broken keyboard are gone.